# how to implement dynamic update sql in spring

Tags: java, mysql, spring

```
public void updateById(Suser user) {
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    sql.append("update " + TABLE_NAME + " u");
    sql.append(" set");
    sql.append(" user_name=:userName,password=:password,role=:role,enable=:enable,service_pwd=:servicePwd,cluster_id=:clusterId");
    sql.append(" where");
    sql.append(" id=:id");

    params.put("userName", user.getUserName());
    params.put("password", user.getPassword());
    params.put("role", user.getRole());
    params.put("enable", user.isEnable());
    params.put("id", user.getId());
    params.put("servicePwd", user.getServicePwd());
    params.put("clusterId", user.getCluster().getId());
    getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().update(sql.toString(), params);
}
```

Here is the current DAO layer, how can i do if use just one method to update part of the columns ? Columns that need to update could be different eachtime.

append dynamic sql or aleady have a concise way in spring?

Comment: How do you tell the method which columns need to be updated? Are all other fields of the ``Suser`` instance null?

Comment: @f1sh umm.actually, i do not want to tell which column i need by [is null]. i really do not like the way which execute sql directly. So have another method or platform can solve this ?

Comment: you can either create your own query string by appending only the relevant columns or, if you don't want to mess with sql queries, you have to look into an ORM mapper such as hibernate.

Comment: @f1sh   I know hibernate can build dynamic sql string, here we just use spring jdbc. So if spring jdbc can't achieve, i'll look at other platform. Thankx

Comment: if you want an sql statement that only updates specific columns, you need some way to designate which columns they are. I would simply try and make a dynamic query, there's nothing ugly about it.

Answer (score 0):

update table_name set column_name='SYSDATE - 30/1440';
This query will add 30mins from the existing time and u can change the values accordingly to change the time.